# Connect array of emails to html file

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm working in apps script right now and want to show an array in my html select dropdown. I've tried connecting it but the dropdown shows up blank when I do. Here's what I have:

EDIT
I've realised that the issue is that the GmailApp function does not work in the html file, and can't figure out how to run it.

```
    <div class ="custom-select"><td class="standard"><select id="select"></select> </td></div>

    <script>

        // get drafts
        var drafts = GmailApp.getDrafts();
        var drafty = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < drafts.length; i++)
        {
            drafty.push(drafts[i].getMessage().getSubject());
        }

        var select = document.getElementById("select"),
                 arr = drafty

         for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
         {
             var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
                 txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
             option.appendChild(txt);
             option.setAttribute("value",arr[i]);
             select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
         }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the right value here?

```
txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
```

Try with something like this

```
       var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
         txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
         option.innerHTML.appendChild(txt);
         option.value(arr[i]);
         select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the select is still showing up blank as if nothing is being passed to it.

Comment: Change the last line: 

 select.options.add(option);

If this does not work verify if the problem comes before adding the value

Comment: That doesn't work as I realised that the issue is that GmailApp won't work inside the html.

Comment: I hope you can fix it as you wanted

Comment: Thanks! Still not sure how to run GmailApp inside html, but I'll post an update if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
          txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);

        option.setAttribute("value", arr[i]);
        option.appendChild(txt);
        document.getElementById("select").appendChild(option);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it also just shows up blank, it's really strange as it works when I manually input an array. I think the issue may be with calling GmailApp inside HTML file, but not completely sure.

Comment: check the length of drafty array with a quick console.log(drafty.length)

Comment: I can't get the length, as drafty isn't being populated at all because the GmailApp function won't work. Is there a way that I could write it in an external file and connect to the html?

Answer (score 0):

### `GmailApp` is an Apps Script class that must be called serverside

There are several ways to do it, I recommend in your case:

If you have a `code.gs` and an `html` filed in your WebApp, you can call from within the `<script> ... </script>` part from the `html` part the `code.gs` part with the method [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).

Sample:

> code.gs

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index'); 
}
function getDrafts(){
  var drafts = GmailApp.getDrafts();
  var drafty = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < drafts.length; i++)
    {
      drafty.push(drafts[i].getMessage().getSubject());
    }
  return drafty;
}
```

> index.html

```
...
<script>
...
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getDrafts();
  function onSuccess(drafty) {
        var select = document.getElementById("select"),
        arr = drafty;
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
         {
             ...
         }
...
</script>
...
```

Alternatively, you could also use [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to call Apps Script functions inside your HTML code.